# <%#Eval %> in asp.net to move page

Tags: html, asp.net, http, hyperlink, eval

Like other 'List' page, I'm making a `<a>` tag on td, and 3buttons 'Go up','Go down','Go list'.

I succeed after click this link, go another page.

```
  <a href="NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=<%#Eval("Seq") %>"><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

Now, the problem is here. To make Go up/down pages, I guess put the number `+1` on the link to calculate page number.

```
 <a href="NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=<%#Eval("Seq") %> +1"><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

Then, when I check address, result just show +1 not calculate.

```
 //address : http://localhost:61375/NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=+1
```

How can I calculate on Eval Databinding data and show that? or, do you know how to make a function up/down page with Eval?

Comment: Do you want to add and subtract 1 from the value you are getting from database to generate hyper links for next and previous buttons?

Comment: @Joker yes, that's right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string value in the database and you expect it to always be an integer and it shouldn't be `null`, then you should use `int.Parse()`

```
<a href="NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=<%# (int.Parse(Eval("Seq").ToString()) + 1) %>"><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

---

Otherwise if you don't know the type of data and you don't sure about the `null` values then should use `Convert.ToInt32()`. `Convert.ToInt32()` returns `0` for `null`, while `int.Parse()` throws a `ArgumentNullException`

```
<a href="NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Seq")) + 1) %>"><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Specific explanation

Answer (score 1):

You're not parsing the `int`, try this (if your `int` is nullable though, make sure you check for that first):

```
<a href='NoticeDetail.aspx?seq=<%# int.Parse(Eval("Seq").ToString()) + 1 %>'><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

Comment: it says error message, `The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @naanace Check my updated edit, I forgot to `.ToString()` the `Eval` first, as that's an `object`